# MVC DropDown - Assigning Values from Entity instead of Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

In my Razor view the below line works perfectly.

```
@Html.DropDownList("temp", Model.DropDownCategories);
```

In one of my scenario i have created a Shared View which i can access from any other view.

where am assigning model to  an Entity

```
SampleEntity sam = new SampleEntity();

sam.DropDownCategories = Model.DropDownCategories;
```

And am passing this Entity to shared View by calling a function and am trying to create a DropDown in that view by below code

```
@Html.DropDownList("siteType",sam.DropDownCategories);
```

But am getting a Compile time error

```
cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.WebPages.Html.SelectListItem>'
```

If i directly assign from Model DropDown works fine. But failing when i use Entity of same Type.

Any solution would be great !

Comment: Please show us how you define your `Model` and your `SampleEntity`

Comment: @RédaMattar Mattar My Property in model as well as Entity for DropDown is same. just am storing in one entity from model and passing that to Razorgenerated View